# Displaying all blog posts with Gatsby Contentful

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, contentful

Im trying to display all my Contentful blog posts to my index page in Gatsby but i get an error.

im creating the Posts pages on `gatsby-node.js` like this:

```
const path = require(`path`)
// Log out information after a build is done
exports.onPostBuild = ({ reporter }) => {
  reporter.info(`Your Gatsby site has been built!`)
}
// Create blog pages dynamically
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const blogPostTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/blogPost.js`)
  const result = await graphql(`
    query {
      allContentfulPost {
        edges {
          node {
            postTitle
            slug
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  result.data.allContentfulPost.edges.forEach(edge => {
    createPage({
      path: `${edge.node.slug}`,
      component: blogPostTemplate,
      context: {
        title: edge.node.postTitle,
        slug: edge.node.slug,
      },
    })
  })
}
```

based on this template:

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import styled from "styled-components"

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
    post: contentfulPost(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
      slug
      postTitle
      postContent {
        childMarkdownRemark {
          html
        }
      }
      postImage {
        title
        fluid {
          src
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

function blogPost({ data }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <img
        src={data.post.postImage.fluid.src}
        alt={data.post.postImage.title}
      ></img>
      <h1>{data.post.postTitle}</h1>
      <h3
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: data.post.postContent.childMarkdownRemark.html,
        }}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default blogPost
```

Now i try to create a component which will hold all the blog posts so i can display it on my `index.js` page, like this:

```
import { Link, graphql, StaticQuery } from "gatsby"
import React from "react"
import styled from "styled-components"

function BlogSection() {
  return (
    <StaticQuery
      query={graphql`
        query blogQuery {
          
          allContentfulPost {
            edges {
              node {
                slug
                postTitle
                postImage {
                  file {
                    url
                    fileName
                  }
                }
                postContent {
                  postContent
                }
                postDate
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `}
      render={data => (
        <ul>
          <Link to={data.allContentfulPost.edges.node.slug}> //here's where the error happens
            {data.allContentfulPost.edges.node.postTitle}
          </Link>
        </ul>
      )}
    />
  )
}

export default BlogSection
```

But i get an error `Cannot read property 'slug' of undefined` which is driving me crazy for days.

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: edges is an array

Comment: @xadm so what should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
<ul>
  {data.allContentfulPost.edges.map(({ node }) => {
    return <Link to={node.slug} key={node.slug}>
    {node.postTitle}
  </Link>
  })}
</ul>
```

You are querying all pots from Contentful (`allContentfulPost`) which following the nested structure, has an `edges` and a `node` inside: this last one has all the information of your posts (because of the nested structure, you have the `slug`, the `postTitle`, etc) so the `node`, is indeed your post. That said, you only need to loop through `edges`, which is an array of your posts. In the previous snippet:

```
data.allContentfulPost.edges.map(({ node })
```

You are destructuring the iterable variable at the same time you loop through it (`{ node }`). You can alias it for a more succint approach like:

```
<ul>
  {data.allContentfulPost.edges.map(({ node: post }) => {
    return <Link to={post.slug} key={post.slug}>
    {post.postTitle}
  </Link>
  })}
</ul>
```

It's important to use the [`key` attribute](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) in all loops since it will help React to know what elements are changing.

Comment: i thank you zillion times! somehow i knew the logic around this but im new and my syntax was always wrong. this worked the first time i refreshed. any idea how to limit the number of posts to display?

Comment: Thanks :). To limit the posts you have a GraphQL filters (the `limit` one) which should do the trick. Use the `localhost:8000/___graphql` playground to test your queries and filters

Comment: thanks a lot! it works. only one more question pls :) how can i make the slug dynamic? for example when i click on the post from another page it returns 404. for instance i display the posts in home page and in the blog page. when i click on the post from the homepage, the slug is `domain.com/post` but when i click from the blog page its `domain.com/blog/post` and it returns 404. heres my query from the template page: `query($slug: String!) {
    post: contentfulPost(slug: { eq: $slug })`

Comment: Open a new answer please. It's difficult to see the code this way. Check Gatsby's tutorial, this configuration is on `gatsby-node.js`

Comment: heres my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67143815/gatsby-dynamic-slug