# Gatsby dynamic slug

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby, contentful

First I'm gonna present the code I have and then explain the problem:

I'm having this on my `gatsby-node.js`:

```
const path = require(`path`)
const { createFilePath } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`)

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, getNode, actions }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions
  if (node.internal.type === `ContetnfulPost`) {
    const slug = createFilePath({ node, getNode, basePath: `pages` })
    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: `slug`,
      value: slug,
    })
  }
}
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const result = await graphql(`
    query {
      allContentfulPost {
        edges {
          node {
            postTitle
            slug
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  const posts = result.data.allContentfulPost.edges

  posts.forEach(({ node }, index) => {
    createPage({
      path: `${node.slug}`,
      component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/blogPost.js`),
      context: {
        slug: node.slug,
        prev: index === 0 ? null : posts[index - 1].node,
        next: index === posts.length - 1 ? null : posts[index + 1].node,
      },
    })
  })
}
```

Then I'm querying blog posts in 2 places: one as a blog page like this:

`blog.js` page:

```
function Blog() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <SEO title="Blog Page" />
      <StaticQuery
        query={graphql`
          query blogQuery {
            allContentfulPost {
              edges {
                node {
                  slug
                  postTitle
                  postImage {
                    file {
                      url
                      fileName
                    }
                  }
                  postContent {
                    postContent
                  }
                  postDate
                }
              }
            }
          }
        `}
        render={data => (
          <ul>
            {data.allContentfulPost.edges.map(({ node }) => {
              return (
                <BlogPostsContainer>
                  <Link to={`${node.slug}`}>
                    <BlogPostImage src={node.postImage.file.url} />
                    <PostTitle>{node.postTitle}</PostTitle>
                  </Link>
                </BlogPostsContainer>
              )
            })}
          </ul>
        )}
      />
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

And the other, a react component which I use to display some of my posts in the homepage:

`BlogSection.js`

```
function BlogSection() {
  return (
    <BlogSectionWrapper>
      <StaticQuery
        query={graphql`
          query homeBlogQuery {
            allContentfulPost(limit: 2) {
              edges {
                node {
                  slug
                  postTitle
                  postImage {
                    file {
                      url
                      fileName
                    }
                  }
                  postContent {
                    postContent
                  }
                  postDate
                }
              }
            }
          }
        `}
        render={data => (
          <ul>
            {data.allContentfulPost.edges.map(({ node }) => {
              return (
                <HomePostsContainer>
                  <Link to={`${node.slug}`}>
                    <HomePostImage src={node.postImage.file.url} />
                    <PostTitle>{node.postTitle}</PostTitle>
                  </Link>
                </HomePostsContainer>
              )
            })}
          </ul>
        )}
      />
      <ButtonWrapper></ButtonWrapper>
      <FlatButton
        item={{
          title: "See all posts",
          icon: "/images/icons/book.svg",
          link: "/blog",
        }}
      />
    </BlogSectionWrapper>
  )
}
```

Now the problem is that when I click in a blog post from the home page (the ones rendered from the `BlogSection.js` component), the URL is normally `http://localhost:8000/test-post`.

But when I click on a post from the blog page (rendered from the `blog.js` file), the URL becomes `http://localhost:8000/blog/test-post`.

I also added `Prev` and `Next` buttons on each post and when I click on them, it just appends the slug in the URL, for instance when I'm on `http://localhost:8000/test-post` and click `Next`, it becomes `http://localhost:8000/test-post/test-post2`.

How can I keep the URL to show the post slug only or maybe with a `/blog` prefix for all the posts independent from where I click on it?

I tried this on the `gatsby-node.js` file but its not working:

```
posts.forEach(({ node }, index) => {
    createPage({
      path: `/blog/${node.slug}`, //<===== THIS LINE
      component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/blogPost.js`),
      context: {
        slug: node.slug,
        prev: index === 0 ? null : posts[index - 1].node,
        next: index === posts.length - 1 ? null : posts[index + 1].node,
      },
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dynamic posts are being created at `localhost:8000/:post-slug` not under `/blog/:post-slug` because of:

```
  path: `${node.slug}`,
```

So, the first step is to add the following (what you've tried so far):

```
posts.forEach(({ node }, index) => {
    createPage({
      path: `/blog/${node.slug}`, 
      component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/blogPost.js`),
      context: {
        slug: node.slug,
        prev: index === 0 ? null : posts[index - 1].node,
        next: index === posts.length - 1 ? null : posts[index + 1].node,
      },
    })
  })
```

After that, keep in mind that all links that are not prefixed by `/`, will be concatenated to the current URL, like what happens with the standard anchor (`<a>` tag). Just adding a `/` at the beginning of the slug should do the trick. That explains this issue:

> I also added Prev and Next buttons on each post and when I click on
> them, it just appends the slug in the URL, for instance when I'm on
> `http://localhost:8000/test-post` and click Next, it becomes
> `http://localhost:8000/test-post/test-post2`.

Now, if you want, for example, to go from the home page to a specific post, you will need to add the `/blog` to the URL since it's not a part of the post slug:

```
function BlogSection() {
  return (
    <BlogSectionWrapper>
      <StaticQuery
        query={graphql`
          query homeBlogQuery {
            allContentfulPost(limit: 2) {
              edges {
                node {
                  slug
                  postTitle
                  postImage {
                    file {
                      url
                      fileName
                    }
                  }
                  postContent {
                    postContent
                  }
                  postDate
                }
              }
            }
          }
        `}
        render={data => (
          <ul>
            {data.allContentfulPost.edges.map(({ node }) => {
              return (
                <HomePostsContainer>
                  <Link to={`/blog/${node.slug}`}>
                    <HomePostImage src={node.postImage.file.url} />
                    <PostTitle>{node.postTitle}</PostTitle>
                  </Link>
                </HomePostsContainer>
              )
            })}
          </ul>
        )}
      />
      <ButtonWrapper></ButtonWrapper>
      <FlatButton
        item={{
          title: "See all posts",
          icon: "/images/icons/book.svg",
          link: "/blog",
        }}
      />
    </BlogSectionWrapper>
  )
}
```

Notice the  `` <Link to={`/blog/${node.slug}`}> ``. And do the same exactly with the `blog.js` template.

The previous behavior was working in `blog.js` because paths are not relative, it was concatenating the post slug to the current URL (`/blog`), but wasn't pointing to `/blog`.

To solve the further issues with that, check all the `slug` and add the `/` (if needed) to avoid concatenating issues.

Summarizing:

- Create the dynamic posts under `/blog/:post-slug` in the `gatsby-node.js`: this will generate all posts under `/blog`
- Point all links to `/blog/:post-slug` no matter the origin URL (home page to post, etc).
- Add a slash (`/`) at the beginning of all links that point to the posts to avoid concatenating and relativity of URL issues. The same workaround applies to the next and previous buttons.

Comment: Thanks @Ferran it works fine. so if i want to add another content model from Contentful, lets say Portfolio, do i have to just duplicate the code in `gatsby-node.js` and query the portfolio schema? or theres another trick with less code?

Comment: You will need to use multiple instances of the queries. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/64594951/5585371

Comment: can you check this also pls: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67248328/gatsby-blog-pagination-disable-button-on-the-last-page