# Gatsby blog pagination disable button on the last page

Tags: reactjs, navigation, gatsby, contentful

I'm setting blog pagination in Gatsby like this:

`gatsby-node.js` File:

```
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const result = await graphql(`
    query {
      allContentfulPost(sort: { order: ASC, fields: [createdAt] }) {
        edges {
          node {
            postTitle
            slug
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

const postsPerPage = 2
  const numPages = Math.ceil(posts.length / postsPerPage)
  Array.from({ length: numPages }).forEach((_, i) => {
    createPage({
      path: i === 0 ? `/blog` : `/blog/${i + 1}`,
      component: path.resolve("./src/templates/blog.js"),
      context: {
        limit: postsPerPage,
        skip: i * postsPerPage,
        numPages,
        currentPage: i + 1,
      },
    })
  })
}
```

then in `blog.js` file i add the buttons and the page numbers like this:

```
function Blog({ pageContext, data }) {
  const { currentPage, numPages } = pageContext
  const isFirst = currentPage === 1
  const isLast = currentPage === numPages
  const prevPage = currentPage - 1 === 1 ? "" : (currentPage - 1).toString()
  const nextPage = (currentPage + 1).toString()
  return ( 

    <PaginationContainer>
              <FlatButton
                item={
                  !isFirst && {
                    title: "Previous Page",
                    icon: "/images/icons/left-arrow.svg",
                    link: `/blog/${prevPage}`,
                  }
                }
              />
    
              <PageNumbersContainer>
                {Array.from({ length: numPages }, (_, i) => (
                  <PageNumber
                    item={{
                      title: `${i + 1}`,
                      icon: "",
                      link: `/blog/${i === 0 ? "" : i + 1}`,
                      key: `pagination-number${i + 1}`,
                    }}
                  />
                ))}
              </PageNumbersContainer>
    
              <FlatButton
                item={
                  !isLast && {
                    title: "Next Page",
                    icon: "/images/icons/right-arrow.svg",
                    link: `/blog/${nextPage}`,
                  }
                }
              />
            </PaginationContainer>

)}
```

now when theres no previous page or next page, in the button the `title` dissapears and only the container is there.

i want to keep the title and the button shape to stay as it is but to make it disabled (un-cklickable)

i'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the `title` you just need to remove the condition and leave the component like:

```
          <FlatButton
            item={
              {
                title: "Next Page",
                icon: "/images/icons/right-arrow.svg",
                link: `/blog/${nextPage}`,
              }
            }
          />
```

To make the button disabled you have multiple workarounds. The most simple and native is, if your `FlatButton` component extends from any `button` tag, you can pass an `isDisabled` `prop` like:

```
          <FlatButton
            item={
              {
                isDisabled: isLast
                title: "Next Page",
                icon: "/images/icons/right-arrow.svg",
                link: `/blog/${nextPage}`,
              }
            }
          />
```

Then, in your component:

```
const FlatButton = ({ item })=>{

  return <button disabled={item.isDisabled}>{item.title}</button>
}
```

Of course, without knowing how your `FlatButton` looks like you'll need to tweak it a little bit, but you get the idea.

Otherwise, you can play with the class names of the components and use, among other styling, `pointer-events: none` CSS rule.

> how do i select `isDisabled` in css? using styled components

Like all props in styled-components:

```
  color: ${props => props.isDisabled? "white" : "red"};
```

Comment: how do i select `isDisabled` in css? using styled components. i tried as css attribute `[isDisabled] { color: red }` but its not working.

Comment: Use something like: `color: ${props => props.isDisabled? "white" : "red"};`

Comment: is `disabled` a `Link` attribute in Gatsby? im using `Link` as button not a react button

Comment: It's not, but you can customize your component whatever you like using CSS, styled-components etc. In the end, you are styling so it's not matter the component, only the rule applied

Comment: i did this on my button component https://prnt.sc/121v6hv and this on the blog page https://prnt.sc/121v4n4 but its not working. i can again click on the buttons. when i switch the styles here pointer-events: ${props => (props.isDisabled ? "auto" : "none")}; both buttons become disabled which mean something with isDisabled={isLast} is not working

Comment: Can you debug to see if the value of the prop (isFirst or isLast) is arriving properly? In addition, you should switch the props.... If a button doesn't have previous means that is the first one... (And the opposite for the last). The styled component looks good and my workaround should fix your issue but the implementation is not good

Comment: i tried switching the props. also tried `!isFirst` `!isLast` (exclamation mark) but dosent work.

Comment: Please, can you debug a little bit more? What props are arriving and it's value??? If they're not being refreshed you may need to use a state

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231594/discussion-between-ferran-buireu-and-ilir).